# use def exception cannot be converted to throwable error

Tags: java, exception

```
public class Odexception extends Exception {
     double deficit;
     Odexception(String msg,double def) {
         super(msg);
         this.deficit=def;
     }
}


public   void withdraw(double amt)  throws odexception {
     if(amt<=balance) {
         balance=balance-amt;
     } else {
          throw new Odexception("Insufficient balance",amt-balance);
     }
}

public static void main(string ar[]) {
     try{
        c[0].acc[0].withdraw(2000);
     } catch(Odexception  e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
}
```

Comment: `if (question.indexOf('?') < 0) System.exit(1);`

Comment: Your question is not very clear can you say what you want to achieve actually??

Comment: @M.Sharma  want to print msg,when amt>bal as insuff balance using Exception.

Comment: I hope those two code snippets are from different classes, as i cannot see a class encapsulating main() and withdraw().Also what problem are you facing ?

Comment: @Mustafasabir  during compilation it shows odexception cannot be convrrted to Throwable

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want right?

```
class Odexception extends Exception{
    double deficit;
    Odexception(String msg,double def) {
        super(msg);
        this.deficit=def;
    }
}

public class CustomException {
    double balance;
    public CustomException(double balance)
    {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amt) throws Odexception {
        if (amt <= balance) {
            {
                balance = balance - amt;
                System.out.println("Withdrawn : "+amt+"\nCurrent Balance is :"+balance);
            }
        } else {
            throw new Odexception("Insufficient balance", amt - balance);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        try {
            new CustomException(1000).withdraw(5000);
        } catch (Odexception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```